# Using Visual Studio 2010 to develop for Windows 2k/2k3 servers

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, .net-2.0

Is it problematic to use Visual Studio 2010 to develop a C# .NET 2.0 console application for windows 2k/2k3 server (with .NET 2.0 installed)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's not. All you have to do is to compile your assembly for .NET 2.0. Right click on the project, select properties, Target Framework -> .NET Framework 2.0

Answer (score 3):

No. You can target your framework to 2.0 for your console project in VS2010.

Answer (score 1):

No. VS2010 allows developing for .NET 2.0, 3.0, 3.5 or 4.0.